# How do I add keyboard navigation to a svelte app (other than window object)?

Tags: svelte

I would like add keyboard navigation to my svelte app. I know it's possible using svelte's window object like `<svelte:window on:keydown={handleKeydown}/>`. Yet the resulting code is not very nice since it spreads usage of the window object over the whole app.

Ideally I would like to use a syntax similar to vue where it's possible to write `<input v-on:keyup.page-down="onPageDown">`.

Is something like that possible in svelte as well? Did I miss any svelte add-ons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach an event listener to the input element :

```html
<input on:keyup={handleKeyUp}/>

<script>
  function handleKeyUp(event) {
    // ..
  }
</script>
```

If you want the same syntax as the one in your question, you can use an action like this one :

```html
<input use:keyup={{PageDown: onPageDown}}/>

<script>
  import { keyup } from './keyup.js';

  function onPageDown() { ... }
</script>
```

```js
export function keyup(node, map) {
    
    const listener = (e) => { if (map[e.key]) map[e.key](e); }
    
    node.addEventListener("keyup", listener);
    
    return {
        destroy() { node.removeEventListener("keyup", listener); }
    }
}
```

See it in the repl [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/c6ad343f3ec2406aaae05cf8b4a20698?version=3.23.2) and the doc about svelte action [here](https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action)